# Unable to include jpegLib.h from Different location?

Tags: c++

I am building a library using vs2005. And  I am using makefile system to build it. In the include section I have included both "../vc/include/" folder and also a jpeg third party library in the same order as I mentioned their names. Since Jpeg library inclusion is after vc/include so I think all files which are in both folders should be included from jpeg library.

But currently it is picking all files from vc/include. Is this behavior is correct, if yes kindly suggest me the correct one. If no then tell me where I could have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No you misunderstand, add the paths to your include path just means the files in those paths are visible to your code so you can `#include` them it doesn't mean that all files in those folders will be `#include`d by this act. You still need to explicitly need `#include "jpegLib.h"` in your code somewhere.

Also are you separating the paths with a `;` semi colon and are they relative to where VC++ resides?